# overriding equals and hashcode ignoring the case?

Tags: java

I have below pojo overridden equls and hashcode.

```
class Name {  
    private String name;  

    public Name(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  

    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  

    public int hashCode() {  
        return name.toLowerCase().hashCode();  
    }  

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {  
        if (!(obj instanceof Name) return false;  
        return name.toLowerCase().equals(((Name) obj).name.toLowerCase());  
    }  
}
```

In above code i am doing lower case while generating hash code. Is it good practice?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you anticipating as valid characters?  Note that not all languages have the concept of "lower case" (ie, Japanese, Chinese), and some upper/lower changes depend on language (English versus Turkish, I think it was).  Probably what you're really looking for is some sort of Unicode canonicalization, which would help clear up some related issues too.  If you're going to be doing these comparisons a bunch, you may want to also store the "comparison" form, so it doesn't have to be derived each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about good or bad practice. It's about your own needs and the sense of equality related to your objects.

In this very case, if your `equals` method should return `true` ignoring the case, your `hashCode` method is implemented accordingly. This is true because one of the rules for implementing `equals` and `hashCode` together states that **if two objects are semantically equal (that is, the equals method returns true for the two objects), then their hash codes should be equal**.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to introduce another field

```
String lowerCaseName;
```

then `hashCode` would be more efficient

`return lowerCaseName.hashCode()`

Also in `equals` I'd use `String.equalsIgnoreCase` for the same reason

```
return name.equalsIgnoreCase((((Name) obj).name);
```

Answer (score 0):

overriding of equals and hashcode actually done to meet the necessity. if your requirements is to show two strings equals even if they have different case (upper or lower) then I think there is no harm to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare String Objects ignoring case the below code will do

```
String hello_caps = "HELLO";
String hello = "hello";
hello.equalsIgnoreCase(hello_caps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Five review points:

1) Why call the class `Name` when all your doing is implementing a string with a lower case comparison and hash? The class could be useful for other things so call it something more generic.

2) You're taking a deep copy of the string to effect the lower case conversion each time you compute the hash. Hash functions are supposed to be fast. At least cache the lower case equivalent.

3) Think carefully about the relationship between `hashCode()` and `toString()`.

4) Add `@Override` annotations where appropriate.

5) `name` could be `null`. In which case `hashCode()` will throw a Null Pointer Exception.

There's nothing wrong with the *idea* though, although, personally, I'd just use a standard string and use `equalsIgnoreCase()`. Then your code will be easier to maintain as it will be more standard.

Comment: 3) Think carefully about the relationship between hashCode() and toString(). -- What's the relationship between `hashCode()` and `toString()` ? I mean, why it should be thought carefully?